# Declare a custom selector in scss?

Tags: sass

For example, I want to select element by attribute `ng-controller` (as in angularjs). I have a div with

```
<div ng-controller="foo1Ctrl"></div>
<div ng-controller="foo2Ctrl"></div>
<div ng-controller="foo3Ctrl"></div>
```

In scss, I would have to do:

```
[ng-controller="foo1Ctrl"] {}
[ng-controller="foo2Ctrl"] {}
[ng-controller="foo3Ctrl"] {}
```

To produce my scoped or nested css.
Is it possible for me to define some macro in scss?

(In C form, it would be something along this line)

```
#DEFINE ng(x) [ng-controller="x"]

ng(foo1Ctrl) {}
ng(foo2Ctrl) {}
ng(foo3Ctrl) {}
```

I just wonder if scss do have something along this line. If it doesn't have one, then I'll just use the original method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation shows pretty much everything you can do in Sass:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content

```
@mixin ng($value) {
    [ng-controller="#{$value}"] {
        @content;
    }
}

@include ng('asdf') {
    color: red;
}
```

Output:

```
[ng-controller="asdf"] {
  color: red;
}
```